# Which is the standard notation for an infinite summation (or any summation-like operator) without indexes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation, infinity, index-notation

An infinite indexed summation is written as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i$.
A summation of items in a set, finite or not, is $\sum\limits_{c\in C} c$.
How should I represent an infinite sum of the same thing over and over?
Is just $\sum c$ clear enough? Or...

$\sum\limits^\infty c$

$\sum\limits^\infty_{\_} c$

ps.
A more appealing example is perhaps the big X from `\varprod` which isn't available here.
One of the use cases is to represent a "stream" of Cartesian products that can be zipped to another, finite, one and discard the excess. Actually, the tuples will be zipped, but the result is the same anyway.

ps.2 -
It is something to be written several times in an algebraic expression. Like a language to define a system, so the less verbose the better.

Comment: Not without enough context to make the underlying index set (or at least its cardinality) clear. If you’re just adding an infinite or bi-infinite sequence of copies of $c$ you can write $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}c$ or $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}c$, for instance. If you’re adding $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ copies, you can write $\sum_{\alpha\in\Bbb R}c$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Nice point about "bigger" infinities!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, shouldn't we use $c_k$ instead? I.e. $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}c_k$ and $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}c_k$

Comment: @JDoeDoe: It’s not necessary, and sometimes it’s absolutely wrong; e.g., in $\sum_{k=1}^n1=n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, you can write:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c $$
(since $c$ does not depend on $k$, it is clear that you mean an infinite sum of the same element).

Comment: Can I just omit the $k$ and keep the $\infty$? Or perhaps, put a placeholder below the summation?

Comment: It is something to be written several times in an algebraic expression.

Comment: Usually, the index is written explicitely (because, otherwise, $c$ could be interpreted as the actual index, changing the meaning of the expression). You may also write $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} c$, for instance, as suggested by @Brian M. Scott.

Comment: Shouldn’t c be indexed by k such that we have $c_k$?

Comment: If you write $c_k$, you are stressing the dependence on $k$, which is not what you are trying to do here (of course, $c_k =c$ for all $k$ is a possibility, but then it is better to simply write $c$ instead of $c_k$).